# Learn a new language in between the non speakers environment (Same native language as mine)

Tags: learning-methods, french

I am planning to learn French as my third language. I am native Hindi speaker and my second language is English. I was going through few websites how to learn. Then I came to this video [How to learn any language in six months | Chris Lonsdale | TEDxLingnanUniversity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0yGdNEWdn0) and it states - Use new language as a tool to communicate from day 1. Secondly he says you should know how they other person communicate by oserving their body language, the mouth and the facial expressions. The problem is I am surrounded by people who are not speakers of French. So what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could watch french youtubers. Youtubers speak the language you'd listen in the street and you can see their body language and expressions.
Also you could watch this:
[Easy Languages - French](https://www.youtube.com/user/magauchsein/playlists?view=50&sort=dd&shelf_id=20)

Comment: wow! how this simple thought didn't came into my mind. BTW thank you.